# Change function with checkboxes and multiple selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, statements

I'm trying to limit the number of two different types of checkboxes  checked at the same time. I want to create a specific combination of boxes checked and then fire an alert, three yellow ones and two red. My problem is that the alert only fires on only one of the statements and not on both. 
I can check only two red but as many yellow as I want.

```
$('input[name=redChoice], input[name=yellowChoice]').change(function() {

    var cntRed = $('input[name=redChoice]:checked').length;
    var cntYellow = $('input[name=yellowChoice]:checked').length;

    var maxRedAllowed2 = 2;
    var maxYellowAllowed3 = 3;

    if (cntRed > maxRedAllowed2 && cntYellow > maxYellowAllowed3) {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
        alert("Du har valt 3 stycken gula och 2 stycken röda."); 
    }
});
```

Comment: can you post  your HTML?

Comment: I think you need to use `||` rather than `&&`

Comment: Maybe use `>=` instead of `>`.

Comment: See here http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/gco7tu8a/

Comment: I've tried your fiddle @Sandeep but the alert fires as soon as one of the statements is met. I would like it to fire when both statements is met.

Comment: @Christine: http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/gco7tu8a/2/  see updated fiddle

Comment: @SandeepNayak if you're going to go to the trouble of attempting to solve this issue, why not write a detailed answer as to what you've changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I believe this is what you are looking for.

You want to be able to click no more than 2 red and 3 yellow and at the same time, you want to show an alert if there are 2 reds and 3 yellows clicked

```js
$('input[name=redChoice], input[name=yellowChoice]').change(function() {

    var cntRed = $('input[name=redChoice]:checked').length;
    var cntYellow = $('input[name=yellowChoice]:checked').length;

    var maxRedAllowed2 = 2;
    var maxYellowAllowed3 = 3;

    
    
     if (cntRed == maxRedAllowed2 && cntYellow == maxYellowAllowed3) {
        //$(this).prop('checked', false);
        alert("Du har valt 3 stycken gula och 2 stycken röda."); 
    }
    else if (cntRed > maxRedAllowed2){
       $(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
    else if (cntYellow > maxYellowAllowed3){
       $(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
red<input type="checkbox" name="redChoice"/>
red<input type="checkbox" name="redChoice"/>
red<input type="checkbox" name="redChoice"/>
red<input type="checkbox" name="redChoice"/>
yellow<input type="checkbox" name="yellowChoice"/>
yellow<input type="checkbox" name="yellowChoice"/>
yellow<input type="checkbox" name="yellowChoice"/>
yellow<input type="checkbox" name="yellowChoice"/>
yellow<input type="checkbox" name="yellowChoice"/>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thank you so much! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Great!. Took a while to understand your question though.

Comment: I'm sorry for that. My first question on here so I'm not used to formulate questions like this. But I got what I wanted so probably it won't be my last time.